inject id into JPA entity for unit testing
With Spring Boot 3 JPA (Kotlin), I have an entity with an id property that is auto-generated. Now I have code which converts such an entity to a DTO (and the id is important in that context). How can I inject an id into the entity to unit test that code? (I don't want to use a heavyweight test with database). The constructor does not allow for passing the id, and I don't want to change the production code.
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
data class User(
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    val createdAt: Instant,
){
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private var id: Int = 0
}

** EDIT: ** I noticed that in the original question the id field was not private. Then I can just assign the id from the outside during my test. I intended to ask about when the id is private, which is the only interesting scenario. I updated the code example accordingly. Sorry for the glitch.

Not quite sure the problem really. Unit tests with JPA generally try to setup an in-memory database for tests. If the production code isn't setup for easy unit testing.. that is a problem with the code design to be honest - but your unit tests can get around it with java reflection to access the properties. This is how some JPA providers do it, as the only requirement of entities is that they have an empty default constructor.

@Chris thank you for sharing your thoughts on this! The test is not about interaction with the database, but about converting the object into a DTO. Setting up an in-memory database for such a test scenario seems inappropriate. My entities follow domain-driven design, and having a non-empty constructor, as in the above example, enforces read-only properties. These can be set only when initializing the object. I use this for keeping business invariants.

Again, that is something I'd push back on personally. Protected access makes for better testing, and for conversion from a DTO to an entity, sometimes all you need is the ID set not a full entity read from the DB.  Saying that, another option is to use your DTO->entity converter if you have full access to the DTO object. Or JSON->DTO->Entity.

Just subclass user in your test. Don't know Kotlin but in Java:     User u =  new User() {         @Override         public int getId() {             return 99;         }     };

My circumstance is different, but you should be able to take ideas from this approach.

I am using Mongo, but still Spring Data / JPA
With my case we generate ids on the client, not the server, but still you can still intercept the Entity and set the Id
I am using MockK, a Kotlin mocking library.  You don't say what you are using, but again the principles transferable to Mockito, etc.

When instantiating the test class, the following function creates a mock Respository which for my purposes simply stores entities in a MutableMap, with just one other function mocked, the findById(..)
EDIT: following OP's edit
You could use reflection to set the private field. Code sample below updated:
private val savedAppointmentsById = mutableMapOf<RULID, MemberAppointment>()

private fun createSemiStatefulAppointmentRepositoryMock(): AppointmentRepository {
    val repository: AppointmentRepository = mockk(relaxed = false)
    savedAppointmentsById.clear()

    every { repository.save(any()) } answers {
        val appointment = firstArg<MemberAppointment>()
        // here you would do something like:
        val id = "new id"
        appointment::class.java.getDeclaredField("id").let {
            it.isAccessible = true
            it.set(appointment, id)
        }
        savedAppointmentsById.put(appointment.id, appointment)
        appointment
    }

    every { repository.findById(any()) } answers {
        Optional.ofNullable(savedAppointmentsById.get(firstArg<RULID>()))
    }
    return repository
}


thank you for your answer. I made a mistake in my code example in the original question - the id field should be private. So, the approach will work for the original question. But if the id is private, I cannot assign it from the outside.

As indicated at the bottom of the question, I made a mistake in the original question, which allows for a much easier solution. But this easy scenario was not what I intended to ask. I know that changing a question after receiving answers for the original question is discouraged - not sure what is the best way to handle this...
